# How to react to a button click in order to change a parameter in a map?

Tags: java, javascript, scala, templates, playframework

I'm using the playframework 2.3.8 and I am trying to implement some sort of Stack Overflow like voting system. Until now I have some questions / answers in a map, that I send to a view. The buttons are there, but I dont know how to make them react to a click in order to change the scoring (arrowUp should upvote the counter, arrowDown similar).

Here is an example picture:

[image: Questions / answers that you can vote on]

This is my Controller **Application.java**:

```
static Map<Question, List<Answer>> myMap = new HashMap<Question, List<Answer>>();

public static void initialize() {
        // Question format: ID / questionText / voteScore / userID
        // Answer format: ID / questionID (answer linked to question) / answerText / voteScore / userID
        Question question1 = new Question("xyz", "Do Androids dream?", 127, "Marcus");
        Answer answer11 = new Answer("zab", "xyz", "Only of electric sheep!", 70, "Tibor");
        Answer answer12 = new Answer("qwert", "xyz", "No, they dont!", 10, "Sarah");

        List<Answer> answerList1 = new ArrayList<Answer>();
        answerList1.add(answer11);
        answerList1.add(answer12);

        myMap.clear();
        myMap.put(question1, answerList1);
}

    public static Result index() {
        initialize();
        return ok(views.html.index.render(myMap));
    }
```

This is my **view class (index.scala.html)**:

```
@import model.Question
@import model.Answer

@(myMap: Map[Question, List[Answer]])

@main("Main") {
@for((question, value) <- myMap){
(some HTML to make it look nice)
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  onclick="voteUp()" id="upvoteButton" 
   value="voteUp" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; text-align: center; vertical-align: center;">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" style="color:orange"></span>
</button>
@question.voteScore
(some HTML to make it look even nicer)
}
```

My **routes.conf**:

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
GET     /                           controllers.Application.upVote()
GET     /Forum                      controllers.Forum.askQuestion()
GET     /Einstellungen              controllers.Application.showSettings()
GET     /Quiz                       controllers.Application.startQuiz()
```

I dont know if I can use the buttons over the route via the controller class as most of other projects seem to use Javascript. So how can you catch the button click and update the voteScore?

**[EDIT1]**: I have added a script now that increments the voteScore of the first question only.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
    function voteUp() {
        var num = $('#num');
        var currentNumber = num.text().length ? parseInt(num.text()) : 0;
        num.text(currentNumber + 1);
    }
</script>
```

In my index.scala.html I have added a span-tag to the @question.voteScore:

```
<span id="num"> @question.voteScore </span>
```

But as I am iterating over a map I can only change the value of the first question. The first upvote Button works, while all others increment the voteScore of the first question also!

So how can I get the respective value from the map for each corresponding question, change it and put it back into the map?

Comment: AJAX (most probably with jQuery) are your answers... Play works in this configuration pretty well, anyway don't expect ready-to-use snippets of code

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I have tried to implement some javascript but ran into another problem. See my EDIT1 please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** you need to do is catch the click event on that button. Use jquery for it, to add event listner to a particular button using class or id.

**Second** you need to make a AJAX call inside event listner, that will hit an API and onSuccess make increment in UI using jquery functions, in case of error show error messge received from API.

**Third** Create an API in Play of POST or GET whichever you want, this API will be called in AJAX from UI. You need to create different API for Voting up Questions and Answers. In both API take id as Parameter and increment the value in DB and then return the incremented value. If there is any error or wrong parameter send error message with statusCode > 300.